# R idiom for vector lookup

Tags: r, vector, lookup

Here is a function which I wrote:

```
lookup <- function (keys, values, key, default) {
  found <- which(keys == key)
  if (length(found) == 1) return(values[found])
  if (length(found) == 0) return(default)
  stop("lookup(",keys,",",values,",",key,",",default,"): duplicate keys")
}
```

and it does what I need just fine:

```
> lookup(c("a"),c(3),"a",0)
[1] 3
> lookup(c("a"),c(3),"b",0)
[1] 0
> lookup(c("a","a"),c(3),"a",0)
Error in lookup(c("a", "a"), c(3), "a", 0) : lookup(aa,3,a,0): duplicate keys
```

the question is: does it look *stylistically* right?
am I missing something?

(specifically, I expect this function to be written as a single expression).

I do understand that this involves full vector lookup and, as such, is inefficient, and I should be using `data.table` if I want this to be fast. Fortunately, the performance in this case is not important as my data is very very small.

Thanks!

Comment: Well for starters the error message is really misleading.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: fixed, thanks (dunno what I was thinking)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

R has dictionaries built into the language via `names`

```
dict <- c("Key1"="val1", "Key2"="val2")

dict[["Key1"]]
# [1] "val1"


dict[["Key3"]]
# Error in dict[["Key3"]] : subscript out of bounds
```

---

#### if you need a function that offers up a default value:

```
getVal <- function(key, dict=defaultDict) { 
  if (! key %in% names(dict) )
    return(defaultValue)

  dict[[key]]
}
```

Comment: So, the OP's function does add the return of a default value, which won't happen with lists. But In general, I agree.

Comment: nice! how do I implement default values? `dict[c("Key1","Key3")]`returns `Key1->val1; NA->NA` instead of `Key1->val1; Key3->NA`

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure why you expect this to be shorter – the logic is in fact in a single expression, just the error handling gets unavoidably messy – and incidentally it’s misleading / wrong. I would also make `default` optional. Then we get:

```
lookup <- function (keys, values, key, default = NULL) {
    if (length(keys) != length(values))
        stop('lookup(', keys, ', ', values, ', ', key, ', ', default,
             '): lengths of keys and values mismatch')
    indices <- which(keys == key)
    if (length(indices) > 1)
        stop('lookup(', keys, ', ', values, ', ', key, ', ', default,
             '): ambiguous match')

    if (length(indices) == 0) default else values[indices]
}
```

Comment: This does not look all that different from my code, so, I guess, this means that my code is not all that bad. Thanks!

Comment: `indices` should be replaced by `found` (or vice-versa) I think

Comment: @sds Yes. The biggest change is essentially that it’s advised to fail as soon as possible – that is, reserve the exceptional (erroneous) case for the [guard clause](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GuardClause) and resume with the normal control flow, rather than doing the inverse as in your code. This also enables us to pack the two expected results into the same `if` and getting rid of the ugly `return`